# Referencing Nested Parameters in Symfony 4 Configuration Files

Tags: symfony4, symfony-components, symfony-config-component

I would like to be able to use nested parameters defined in one  configuration file in another for examle

```
# config/config.yaml (my custom configuration file)
database:
    driver: pdo_mysql
    host: localhost
    user: dev
    password: dev
    dbname: dev
```

To be used in another configuration file

```
# config/packages/doctrine.yaml
url: 'mysql://%database.user%:%database.password%@%database.host%:%database.port%/%database.dbname%'
```

This currently does not work as I am not sure how to reference the variables in the Config package (https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters are just flat key-value elements and can not be nested. This is written in the [Symfony Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parameters.html)

You have to define a separate key for every parameter. The convention is to use a dot to separate namespaces. The dot does not make it an array, but makes it easier to read.

```
database.driver: pdo_mysql
database.host: localhost
database.user: dev
database.password: dev
database.dbname: dev
```

The parameters are then accessed exactly like you want it:

```
url: 'mysql://%database.user%:%database.password%@%database.host%:%database.port%/%database.dbname%'
```